# Webpack 5 plugin: No code generation entry for module error

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin, webpack-5

While upgrading a plugin I'm maintaining to support both Webpack 4 and 5 I've ran into the following brick wall for which I can't find any information at all and no one on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack?at=5f8d68fabbffc02b58271be5) seems to be able to help either.

The plugin adds an asset (SVG spritemap) to `compilation.assets` which is working without problems. There's a feature in the plugin that allows users to keep the created chunk which is needed for interoperability with some other plugins. The minimal working code for Webpack 4 would be along the lines of (and always felt a bit hacky to me, but it worked ‍♂️):

```js
// OutputOptions.chunk.name would equal 'spritemap' in this example
const chunk = compilation.addChunk(outputOptions.chunk.name);
const module = new RawModule('', `${outputOptions.chunk.name}-dummy-module`);

chunk.addModule(module);
```

Using that same approach with Webpack 5 throws the following error:

```
ERROR in spritemap.js
No code generation entry for spritemap-dummy-module (existing entries: <path-to>/svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin/examples/simple/src/index.js)
```

It also shows a deprecation warning for `Chunk.addModule` which I can fix by using `compilation.chunkGraph.connectChunkAndModule(chunk, module);` instead but this (obviously) doesn't get rid of the code generation entry error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up posting the same question as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11829) since I wasn't getting any replies on Gitter and Stack Overflow. Tobias Koppers pushed me in the right direction with a suggestion to make sure the module was added to `compilation.modules`. So in the end this specific issue was solved by the following code:

```js
compilation.modules.add(module);
```